# can defaulted default constructors throw?

Tags: c++, c++11

Defaulted default constructors are generated by the `C++` compiler, the user has no control over them. Can they throw? Is it ok to specify `noexcept` when declaring one?

The following code compiles fine with `gcc`.

```
struct A
{
  A() = default;
};

struct B
{
  B() noexcept = default;
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean defaulted constructors? Or defaulted default constructors?  It's not true that default constructors are generated by the compiler in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is allowed to add a `noexcept` specifier to a defaulted special member function (default constructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator etc.).

A `default` declared special member function will have a `noexcept` specifier depending on the `noexcept` specifiers of the involved functions (its implicit noexcept specifier). If you explicitly specify `noexcept` compilation should fail if this conflicts with the implicit `noexcept` specifier.

Comment: So the compiler will provide the `noexcept` specifier automatically, if applicable?

Comment: This answer would make sense, and I would not be surprised if it is what the standard says, but GCC disagrees. `struct S { int i = (throw 0, 0); S() = default; };` still makes `S`'s constructor `noexcept`, and the exception thrown from the NSDMI cannot be caught.

Comment: @hvd Did you report that to gcc's bugzilla?

Comment: @MarcGlisse No, I didn't. I'm not convinced it's a bug in GCC. The standard says that the `noexcept` specification of implicitly defined member functions depends only on the functions invoked by them. There is no function invoked by the defaulted constructor, so marking the constructor `noexcept` seems to be exactly what the standard requires, even though common sense would suggest otherwise.

Comment: @hvd If it isn't a bug in gcc, it is a bug in the standard then, and reporting it to gcc won't hurt, so please...

Comment: @MarcGlisse I reported a bug regarding some breakage to implicit noexcept specifiers a while ago, but never got much of a response http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59526

Comment: @hvd Implicit noexcept is rather broken on gcc 4.8.2, see the bug I linked in the other reply.

Comment: @pmr Will take a look, if it turns out my new report is a duplicate, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @pmr Possibly similar, but I don't think it's the same. For one thing, in your example, gcc accepts both `noexcept(true)` and `noexcept(false)`, even though the one that doesn't match the one implicitly used should be rejected.

Comment: @hvd Thanks! Philipp, I know, there aren't enough people working on gcc :-( You are welcome to help ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> can default constructors throw?

Yes, they can. For example, if the class has data member(s) whose default constructor throws.

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() { /* throws */} 
};

struct Bar
{
  Bar() = default;
  Foo f;
}
```

Comment: I mean, the programmer must know that the members don't throw and then specify `noexcept`, the compiler won't find this out on its own.

Comment: @user1095108 I don't understand what you are asking. Why would a compiler throw for the heck of it?

Comment: What specifically in the standard prohibits it from doing so.

Comment: @user1095108 That's like asking "What specifically in the standard prohibits a compiler from making `a = b + c;` first set `a` to the sum of `b` and `c`, and then randomly flipping a bit?" The constructors won't throw unless there's something in the standard that says they *can* throw.

Comment: @hvd I agree, but the statement you made, should then be in the standard nonetheless.

Comment: @user1095108 Yes, by specifying `noexcept`, the programmer a promise. If it is broken and an uncaught exception leaves a `noexcept` constructor, `std::terminate` is called.